# How to get the value from a textbox jquery and ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get a value from a textbox and to post it on table, but when I try to console.log the "data" inside the success:function (data), it shows empty data. But if I console it outside the $.ajax it displays the right value.

here's my jquery function

```
function SaveData() {

            var data = $("#inputToDo").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var row = "";
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        console.log(data);
                        row += "<tr><td>" + data + "</td></tr>";
                        $("#bod").html(row);  
                    });
                }
            });
            console.log(data);
            data = $("#inputToDo").val("");
            $("#inputToDo").focus();

    }
```

my html :

```
<input id="inputToDo" name="inputToDo" />
<button id="buttonSave" name="buttonSave" onclick="SaveData()">
    Save
</button>

<table id="tableToDo" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td id ="ToDo"></td>
        <td id ="Execution"></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="bod"></tbody>
</table>
```

any help would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: They are two different `data` variables

Comment: There is no `URL` in ajax function.Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

I've made a working fiddle for you.

I've basicly changed the JavaScript a bit and I assume you have included jquery...

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    SaveData = function(){
        var data = $("#inputToDo").val();
        alert(data);
    }
}
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzvyhkp3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = $("#inputToDo").val();       // outer variable

success: function (data)                //inner variable
{            

            //please note here you are access data variable of success function.
            // which is passed as parameter so outer data variable will always 
            //get override by inner variable
}
```

Solution : Try to change name of outer variable and then try

Answer (score 0):

you are using data as variable(`var data = $ ( "#inputToDo" ). val ();`) and also as an argument (`success :  function  ( data )  {`) .

when you try inside the success-mentod, data will refer to the ajax success response, out side it will refer to the data variable which is your  "#inputToDo" value

instead of using variable data you can yous as inputToDoVal like below code

```
var inputToDoVal = $ ( "#inputToDo" ). val ();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*  <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <label>
                            To Account Number:
                           <input type="text" id="txtcaccno" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" class="form-control" onclick="search();" value="View" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <label>
                            Account Name: 
                            <input type="text" id="txtcaccname" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <label>
                            Account Phone: 
                            <input type="text" id="txtcaccphone" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <label>
                            Account Email: 
                            <input type="text" id="txtcaccemail" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <label>
                            Account Type: 
                           <input type="text" id="txtcacctype" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <label>
                            Balace Amount: 
                            <input type="text" id="txtcamou" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <label>
                            Current Balace Amount: 
                            <input type="text" id="txtcurrcamou" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" class="form-control" onclick="appro();" value="Approved" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>*
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code

```
$("#bod").html(row);
```

to

```
$("#bod").append(row);
```

and it work. Append is used to add the data from jquery to html. Please mark the correct answer if you got the resolution.